# Starting playback on a remote Android device

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Let's assume I have two androide devices. An AndroidTV and a smartphone.
On both devices I have installed my app, that is capable of video playback streamed from a server. 
I want, similar to chromecast, to delegate the playback from my smartphone to the AndroidTV via my app.

How would I do that?
My starting point is this: [Media Router](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html) here I go for Remote Playback.

If I understand this correctly,

- the app on my AndroidTV device would be a MediaRoute Provider,
- the app on my phone would use a MediaRoute to launch a `CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK`-intent on the MediaRoute Provider?

This also means, that the callbacks handle all communication, so that I could differentiate via callbacks between passing the url and let the receiver app fetch title and images themself or let it be passed from the sender app?

Or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the app on my AndroidTV device would be a MediaRoute Provider

No. `MediaRouteProvider` goes on the device that is the user's controller, which in this case would be the phone.

> the app on my phone would use a MediaRoute to launch a CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK-intent on the MediaRoute Provider?

You can do that. The advantage of using `MediaRouteProvider` is that *any* app on that phone that supports `RemotePlaybackClient` can now support your setup. If you only want your app to do this, you could skip `MediaRouteProvider`.

Then, either your app or your `MediaRouteProvider` is responsible for getting the request over to the Android TV device, and your app on it, by some means (WiFiDirect, Bluetooth, GCM over the Internet, whatever). There is nothing in the Android SDK that specifically addresses this -- you're on your own for rolling whatever protocol and connectivity you want. On the plus side, there's no built-in assumption in `MediaRouteProvider` about any particular way to deliver that information, meaning that you could be connecting to something that is not running Android at all.